# In OS X, which key is represented in a shortcut combination by an up arrow with two lines in it?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In OS X, which key is represented in a shortcut combination by an up arrow with two lines in it? It's in the menu after installing the Afloat app.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's [Page Up](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/). No points for guessing what the same but pointing down is.

Comment: Can we simulate that key using laptop's keyboard?

Comment: @the_great_monkey: I think <Fn>-<Up> does it.

Comment: I later learned that Aloat actually allows "scroll up" using the trackpad (two fingers) to activate this command as well. Thanks for the answers! :)